# What is the use of Delta symbol in set theory?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

What is the use of $ \Delta $ in set theory?

Comment: Besides symmetric difference (the answers showing so far), there is the [$\Delta$-lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunflower_(mathematics)) used in forcing arguments and the [diagonal intersection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonal_intersection) of a transfinite sequence of sets of ordinal numbers.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The $\Delta$ in set theory is the symmetric difference of two sets.

$A$ $\Delta$ $B$ $=$ $(B-A) \cup (A-B)$

Comment: And the symbol that should be better used is $\triangle$.

Answer (score 11):

In the context of elementary set theory the symbol $\triangle$ usually denotes the operation of *symmetric difference* of two sets: if $A$ and $B$ are sets, $$A\mathrel{\triangle}B=(A\setminus B)\cup(B\setminus A)\;.$$

This definition explains the name *symmetric difference*: we take both the set difference $A\setminus B$ and the set difference $B\setminus A$ and then form their union, so that the operation is commutative:

$$A\mathrel{\triangle}B=B\mathrel{\triangle}A\;.$$

You ought to prove to yourself that

$$A\mathrel{\triangle}B=(A\cup B)\setminus(A\cap B)\;;$$

this is even sometimes used as the definition of $A\mathrel{\triangle}B$.

In plain English, $A\mathrel{\triangle}B$ is the set of things that belong to exactly one of $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Might be worthwhile to mention associativity, and point to the fact that $(\mathcal P(X), \Delta)$ is an abelian group with unit $\varnothing$.

Comment: @Lord_Farin: I’d rather not: at this point that seems more likely to get in the way than to help. Thanks for catching the dropped letter.

Comment: @Lord_Farin Ring with $\cap$!