# Prove that $ \left( A-B\right) \cup B = A \cup B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

To prove:$ \left( A-B\right) \cup B = A \cup B$
I want it to be done in two ways:1. The algebraic way and 2 Using the method where we say,for example,  $x \in A \text{ or }x\notin B  $(I dont know what that method is called.)
I have done the algebraic method, somebody help me do it using the second method where we assume that let x be a element that belongs to LHS and then we prove that LHS is a subset of the RHS. Then we do it all again but with y such that it belongs to RHS and finally we prove that RHS is a subset of LHS.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the matter? What have you trid? What sort of proof are you looking for - an algebraic proof like the one you wrote below, or a prose proof emphasizing quantifiers?

Comment: @CarlMummert The OP already answered the question

Comment: @CarlMummert I posted this question earlier here:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/566763/what-is-the-use-of-delta-symbol-in-set-theory/ but was asked by lord_farin to make a separate question for it.

Comment: @Amr: yes, but I don't think that is relevant to the issue of the question being written in a way that is not yet suitable for this site. Here is a link to "How to ask a good question": http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question

Comment: @CarlMummert I think it's relevant. Some users post questions and answer it, but I believe their questions are interesting/non-trivial. I consider this question is trivial. It is uninteresting to see a lot of trivial questions on the site. I know trivial questions are being asked, but at least the posters don't know the answer, but I don't think its a good idea to tolerate trivial questions being asked by users who know their answer

Comment: @CarlMummert What about all those people who are voting my question  down. Can you please delete my question so that i dont lose points?

Comment: @shaurya gupta: the best way to get points is to look for other questions you can answer, and write answers to them. You get 10 points for every single up vote on an answer you write. The downvotes here all together are only 10 points. The other thing you can do is edit your question here to make it have more context, and then people can vote it up instead.

Comment: I just edited it and I think it is better, maybe a little bit confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x\in (A-B)\cup B$, then $x\in A-B$ or $x\in B$. If $x\in A-B$, then $x\in A$ and $x\notin B$ and so $x\in A\cup B$. If $x\in B$, then $x\in A\cup B$. Hence $(A-B)\cup B\subset A\cup B$. Let $x\in A\cup B$, then $x\in A$ or $x\in B$. If $x\in A$, then $x\in A\cup B$. If $x\in B$, then $x\in A\cup B$. Hence $A\cup B \subset (A-B)\cup B$. Thus $(A-B)\cup B=A\cup B$.

Comment: Which method should be used when?

Comment: You need to show that the left-hand side is a subset of the right-hand side and that the right-hand side is a subset of the left-hand side.

Comment: What I am asking is which method should i use the algebraic or the one u used?

Comment: The standard way to prove these identities is the way I did it. However, if you can prove this in a different way that is fine too.

Comment: This is the best way to prove that two sets are the same

Answer (score 1):

$ \left( A-B\right) \cup B =  (A \cap B') \cup B = (B \cup A) \cap (B \cup B') = (A \cup B) \cap X = A \cup B $

Note that $A,B \in X$